# ADB for kindle, how to adb to parental controls password prompt

Tags: adb

Im hoping to adb to the parental control page to use a qr code scanner to apply the password? Not sure how to command ADB to open settings to the parental control page reliably. I have used the xy coors to for a simulated push but that is unreliable. Pleas advise. thanks

export from kindle using :
"adb shell dumpsys window windows | findstr com.amazon.parentalcontrols   "

<  C:\FirePlace\package>adb shell dumpsys window windows | findstr com.amazon.parentalcontrols
mTargetAppToken=AppWindowToken{2cb48b1 token=Token{84ecf58 ActivityRecord{27d3c3b u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword t43}}}
Window #6 Window{2cdc3170 u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.password.ParentalPassword}:
mOwnerUid=32106 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.amazon.parentalcontrols appop=NONE
mToken=AppWindowToken{2cb48b1 token=Token{84ecf58 ActivityRecord{27d3c3b u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword t43}}}
mRootToken=AppWindowToken{2cb48b1 token=Token{84ecf58 ActivityRecord{27d3c3b u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword t43}}}
mAppToken=AppWindowToken{2cb48b1 token=Token{84ecf58 ActivityRecord{27d3c3b u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword t43}}}
WindowStateAnimator{558427a com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.password.ParentalPassword}:
mSurface=Surface(name=com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.password.ParentalPassword)
Window #5 Window{ecd92ca u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.gen7.ParentalControlsMainActivityGen7}:
mOwnerUid=32106 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.amazon.parentalcontrols appop=NONE
mToken=AppWindowToken{1388772 token=Token{397cbc7d ActivityRecord{1809c2d4 u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.gen7.ParentalControlsMainActivityGen7 t43}}}
mRootToken=AppWindowToken{1388772 token=Token{397cbc7d ActivityRecord{1809c2d4 u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.gen7.ParentalControlsMainActivityGen7 t43}}}
mAppToken=AppWindowToken{1388772 token=Token{397cbc7d ActivityRecord{1809c2d4 u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.gen7.ParentalControlsMainActivityGen7 t43}}}
WindowStateAnimator{f31aa2b com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.gen7.ParentalControlsMainActivityGen7}:
mSurface=Surface(name=com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.gen7.ParentalControlsMainActivityGen7)
mCurrentFocus=Window{2cdc3170 u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.password.ParentalPassword}
mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{2cb48b1 token=Token{84ecf58 ActivityRecord{27d3c3b u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword t43}}}
mInputMethodTarget=Window{2cdc3170 u0 com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols.password.ParentalPassword}

> 

C:\FirePlace\package>adb shell am start -n com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.amazon.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.parentalcontrols/.password.ParentalPassword} does not exist.

and

C:\FirePlace\package>adb shell monkey -p com.amazon.parentalcontrols -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.